# firebase storage bucket and Fastly CDN integration

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage, fastly

In order for me to get Fastly working with firebase storage I had to add the following permissions on each image and the storage bucket: Entity: User, Name: AllUsers, Access: Reader.  Is there a way to avoid this tedious and unscalable method, since its all user uploaded media?

My firebase storage security looks like the following:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/myapp.appspot.com/o {
match /proUsers/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId || request.resource.size < 2 * 1024 * 1024 || request.resource.contentType.matches('image/png') || request.resource.contentType.matches('image/jpeg'); 
    }
  }
}
```

the error I receive on fastly is that: `Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket`  and if I try to access image directly I get the error: `Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to object`

Where do I allow for anonymous users to have read capabilities? I assumed setting allow read did precisely this.

Answer (score 0):

To allow anonymous users to read from your database (but not write) you can change your rules to this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/myapp.appspot.com/o {
match /proUsers/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId || request.resource.size < 2 * 1024 * 1024 || request.resource.contentType.matches('image/png') || request.resource.contentType.matches('image/jpeg');
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```